# Does Pycharm 5 automates resolving directory?

Tags: python, html, pycharm

Does pycharm 5 support the auto completion of resolving directory in html? If yes, how can I use this feature? I need to resolve the unreferences in the html of my project.

Comment: Do you mean does it auto-complete paths for you? e.g. auto completes template paths?

Comment: @marksweb yeah i need to autofill the path.

Answer (score 0):

If you markup the directories in your project for source root, template root that helps Pycharm know where to look. Just right-click the folders in your project tree and check the 'Mark directory as' submenu.

If you're writing something in a framework like Django you should also ensure you setup the specific settings for that because it'll help you out & enable more features.

Here's the Pycharm docs for [content roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-content-roots.html?search=source%20root)

And this is the docs on [marking directories](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html?search=source%20root) via your project structure that I've mentioned.